# Unable to connect to a socket on a different machine over the same network

Tags: c, sockets, networking

I tried running both of the following server and client programs on the same computer. I ran server with port 5100. Then I ran client with arguments localhost 5100. It works then. But when I ran server on one computer and client on another computer over the same network, client keeps saying ERROR connecting: Connection timed out. When I ran client I sent in the private IP of the server machine and the port number. I tried to ping the server from the client machine and all the packets were transmitted and received so I know that both computers can communicate wih each other. All of the following code was obtained from www.cs.rpi.edu/~moorthy/Courses/os98/Pgms/socket.html . Any help/suggestions would be much appreciated. Thank You.

This is client.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h> 

void error(char *msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(0);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sockfd, portno, n;

    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    struct hostent *server;

    char buffer[256];
    if (argc < 3) {
       fprintf(stderr,"usage %s hostname port\n", argv[0]);
       exit(0);
    }
    portno = atoi(argv[2]);
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockfd < 0) 
        error("ERROR opening socket");
    server = gethostbyname(argv[1]);
    if (server == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no such host\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    bcopy((char *)server->h_addr, 
         (char *)&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr,
         server->h_length);
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
    if (connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) 
        error("ERROR connecting");
    printf("Please enter the message: ");
    bzero(buffer,256);
    fgets(buffer,255,stdin);
    n = write(sockfd,buffer,strlen(buffer));
    if (n < 0) 
         error("ERROR writing to socket");
    bzero(buffer,256);
    n = read(sockfd,buffer,255);
    if (n < 0) 
         error("ERROR reading from socket");
    printf("%s\n",buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

This is server.c

```
/* A simple server in the internet domain using TCP
   The port number is passed as an argument */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

void error(char *msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(1);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
     int sockfd, newsockfd, portno, clilen;
     char buffer[256];
     struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
     int n;
     if (argc < 2) {
         fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no port provided\n");
         exit(1);
     }
     sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
     if (sockfd < 0) 
        error("ERROR opening socket");
     bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
     portno = atoi(argv[1]);
     serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
     serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
     serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
     if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,
              sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) 
              error("ERROR on binding");
     listen(sockfd,5);
     clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);
     newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);
     if (newsockfd < 0) 
          error("ERROR on accept");
     bzero(buffer,256);
     n = read(newsockfd,buffer,255);
     if (n < 0) error("ERROR reading from socket");
     printf("Here is the message: %s\n",buffer);
     n = write(newsockfd,"I got your message",18);
     if (n < 0) error("ERROR writing to socket");
     return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Just check whether your server is listening to the socket. User "netstat -nap" and grep for your port or ip. And if possible take a tcpdump and see what's happening inside.

Comment: This sockets code is ancient, half the functions you use have been removed. That being said, once I `#include`d all the files you missed, changed `server->h_addr` to `server->h_addr_list[0]`, and ignored all the warnings, it worked OK for me, both on the same computer, and across a local network.

Comment: @paulgriffiths So I included the two missing header files    stdlib.h and     string.h and I changed     server->h_addr to    server->h_addr_list[0] in the client.c program yet I'm still getting connection timed out

Comment: @sarath I did netstat -nap with my port# and it says its listening.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths: you're thinking of `bzero()` (use `memset()`), `bcopy()` (use `memmove()` or `memcpy()`) and probably `gethostbyname()` (use [`getaddrinfo()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getaddrinfo.html)
, IIRC); are there any other functions that have been superseded?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Yes, "half" was mild hyperbole. Those were the ones I was thinking of, along with the `h_addr` member of `struct hostent` which is also long gone.

Comment: @user68212: Try telnetting to your server on the port it's listening on, and see if that works. You may have some kind of firewall issue going on, even if you can ping the other machine, doesn't necessarily mean it'll accept a TCP connection on port 5100 from a remote machine. Maybe try swapping which machines the client and server are running on, also, or try a much higher port number.

Comment: @paulgriffiths yep. the issue was that i had incoming connections denied in my firewall settings. Thank you for mentioning about the firewall. It works now.

Comment: You might like to consider changing `error()` to `perror()` as the latter tells you what actually went wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Just to complement the previous answer, if your iptables are blocking data via chain polices, make sure they are in "ACCEPT" mode:

```
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
```

- You may try the same for any other chains you have on the both machines.

Answer (score 0):

The above code is working fine across different machines. Probably the issue you are facing have to do with your iptables or firewall. See the available ports in the server and client side using `iptables -L` and use one of the port which is common in both client and server side.

For example, `iptables -L`

```
    Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
    target     prot opt source               destination         
    ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpts:21100:21299 
    ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpts:21100:21299 
    ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:8092 
    ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp dpt:8091 
    ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:diameter 
    ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:irdmi 
    ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:mysql 
    ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:8092
```

Here you can see that port 8092 is free. So when use this, it will work. Or flush your iptables using `iptables -F` on both machines and try again. There's nothing wrong in the code.